# Redirecting from root to subfolder not working

Tags: .htaccess, webserver, hosting

I wanted to redirect from my root folder to my subfolder. I am not using www sub-domain. I tried solutions given here for previous questions but they are not working for me.
This is the code that is written in my .htaccess file. I placed the file in /home/username/public_html. in the public_html there are two folders, cgi-bin and username. I uploaded my files to username but when I type http://example.com, two folders come up. and after going to example.com/username, my website is visible. So i wrote the following code to redirect

```
RRewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ username [L]
```

To be honest, I dont understand most of it. after putting this, I am getting something like this.

[image: after redirect]

Could you guys help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Possible cause is the misspelling of RRewriteEngine On

That should be RewriteEngine On